# import org.springframework.validation.Validator; and thymeleaf error handling

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

in login.html page I couldn't resolve **th:if="${param.error != null}"** and **th:if="${param.logout != null}"**.
For Validation I use org.springframework.validation.Validator;

here is a github link: https://github.com/MaryGhazaryan/loginregistration111/tree/features.

Answer (score 0):

Thymeleaf couldn't resolve this param, but it works fine.